# Kubernetes apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 Issue with 'Ingress'

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Wanted your guidance on an issue while executing a Kubernetes YAML file.
My kubectl version is as follows:

```
    Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
    Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.14", GitCommit:"89182bdd065fbcaffefec691908a739d161efc03", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-18T12:02:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

This is the latest version downloaded from the Kubernetes site
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows

The YAML has
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
and the error on running the YAML is

```
    no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1"
```

Kubernetes issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90077 mentions that

```
  networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 == 1.14 to 1.18
  networking.k8s.io/v1 = 1.19+
```

So I guess it should be working right?

I have changed the API Version to

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 or
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

but fail in another section of the YAML

```
backend:
  service:
    name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-srv
     port:
       number: 80
```

with the error

error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "service" in io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.IngressBackend

I am informed that the same YAML works on macOS with the same kubectl version (I do not have access to verify that though). But any thoughts on where I could be going wrong?

Thanks,
Prabal

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would like to add that according to the K8 [deprecation guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/), the `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` API versions of `Ingress` is no longer served as of v1.22.

Changes include:

1. The backend `serviceName` field is renamed to `service.name`
2. Numeric backend `servicePort` fields are renamed to `service.port.number`
3. String backend `servicePort` fields are renamed to `service.port.name`
4. `pathType` is now required for each specified path. Options are Prefix, Exact, and ImplementationSpecific.

Meaning we need to make the following changes to go from this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: stackoverflw
  namespace: stacker
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: stacker
          servicePort: 80
```

To this (example):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: stackoverflw
  namespace: stacker
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: stacker
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use below commands to check if kind `Ingress` in version `networking.k8s.io/v1` is available or not in your cluster.

```
kubectl api-resources #List the API resources that are available.
kubectl api-versions  #List the API versions that are available.
```

Answer (score 13):

For `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` it should be

```
backend:
  serviceName: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-srv
  servicePort: 80
```

How to get documentation:

```
kubectl explain --api-version=networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 ingress.spec.rules.http.paths.backend
```

Comment: This helps me to resolve my issue. Thank you, @zerms.

Comment: I really do not see how using the deprecated version helps, issue here is that the one without beta does not work, even though you use K8s 1.19+ version

Comment: @123123d the OP is using 1.18

Answer (score 0):

You can run `helm create mychart` and compare the differences between your chart and the generated chart.

(This is a quick solution, however, the best way to do that is to read the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

you should try something in your ingress.yaml based on env value either -> prd,stg etc

```js
{{- if eq .Values.app.env "prd" }}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: {{ .Values.health_check.httpGet.path }}
  name: {{ .Values.app.env }}-{{ .Values.global.project }}-{{ .Values.app.component }}-{{ .Values.app.type }}-health
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  ingressClassName: {{ (pluck .Values.app.env .Values.ingress.class | first) }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.internal.host }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: {{ .Values.ingress.internal.path }}
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $.Values.app.env }}-{{ $.Values.global.project }}-{{ $.Values.app.component }}-{{ $.Values.app.type }}
            port:
              number: {{ $.Values.service.externalPort }}
{{- end }}
{{ end -}}
```