# Creating a Kubernetes ingress pointing two services

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, gke-networking

Requirement: Want to deploy Minio and another backend service using an ingress with HTTPS (Not for production purposes)

I have been trying to create an ingress to access two services externally from the Kubernetes cluster in GKE. These are the attempts I tried.

Attempt One

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lightning-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /storage
          backend:
            serviceName: minio
            servicePort: 9000
        - path: /portal
          backend:
            serviceName: oscar
            servicePort: 8080
```

Attempt Two

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oscar
  annotations:
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oscar
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: storage.lightningfaas.tech
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: minio
          servicePort: 9000
```

Attempt Three

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lightning-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: minio
          servicePort: 9000
        path: /minio(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: oscar
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /portal(/|$)(.*)
```

Attempt Four

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minio-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: minio.lightningfaas.tech
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: minio
          servicePort: 9000
  - host: portal.lightningfaas.tech
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oscar
          servicePort: 8080
```

However, none of the above attempts suites for my requirement. Either it gives a 404 0r a 503. But I can confirm that creating an individual ingress for each service works fine as below.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oscar
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oscar
          servicePort: 8080
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minio-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: minio
          servicePort: 9000
```

Changing domain servers takes a huge time to test as well, therefore creating hosts are very annoying since I have to wait a massive time to test my code. Is there anything more that I can try?

Something like below would be ideal:

https://34.452.234.45:9000 > will access minio

https://34.452.234.45:8080 > will access oscar

Your suggestions and opinions will be really helpful for me.

Minio helm chart: https://github.com/minio/charts

Minio deployment

```
helm install --namespace oscar minio minio/minio --set accessKey=minio --set secretKey=password --set persistence.existingClaim=lightnig --set resources.requests.memory=256Mi
```

Oscar helm chart: https://github.com/grycap/helm-charts/tree/master/oscar

Oscar deployment

```
helm install --namespace=oscar oscar oscar --set authPass=password --set service.type=ClusterIP --set createIngress=false --set volume.storageClassName=nfs --set minIO.endpoint=http://104.197.173.174 --set minIO.TLSVerify=false --set minIO.accessKey=minio --set minIO.secretKey=password --set serverlessBackend=openfaas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to kubernetes doc, simple fan-out example should solve your problem.
A simple fan-out example is given below where same host has two different paths for two different services.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 4200
      - path: /bar
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
```

So your manifest file might look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: lightning-ingress
    namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: [your host name here]
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /storage
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: minio
            port:
              number: 9000
      - path: /portal
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: oscar
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Ref: [Kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Pulak. But for some reason, it occurs another error ' no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1"'. This doesn't seem to even deploy. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236346/kubernetes-apiversion-networking-k8s-io-v1-issue-with-ingress.

Comment: Are you using k8s version < 1.19 ?